# How to get the user information from access token

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there an endpoint to obtain user information from the access token?

Something similar to below

Oauth2threelegged.getUser(token)
 Ouath2threelegged.validateToken(token)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the API you're looking for? - https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/users-@me-GET/